# Implementing a Macro on Excel

Tags: excel, visual-studio-macros, vba

I have two worksheets in excel.

1. First Worksheet has User vs Transaction Code.
2. Second Worksheet has User vs Module

The Result I want is :

What User has what transaction code and module.

How do I write a macro so I can get to know which user is in which module and has what transaction code.

If anyone could help that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

i think vlookup is one of the possible solutions to your question.

read the following and then try to it.
http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php
http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

ok i think since your new to this, ill explain as much as i can from the basics.
 first the syntax,

VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])

***lookup_value***  The value to search in the first column of the table or range. The lookup_value argument can be a value or a reference.

***table_array***  The range of cells that contains the data. You can use a reference to a range (for example, A2:D8), or a range name. The values in the first column of table_array are the values searched by lookup_value.

***col_index_num***  The column number in the table_array argument from which the matching value must be returned. A col_index_num argument of 1 returns the value in the first column in table_array; a col_index_num of 2 returns the value in the second column in table_array, and so on.

***range_lookup***  true or false depending on whether you want an exact or a close match

[image: example]

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7wvly7ma9gy38mu/1.png

This is a snapshot of excel file.

I want to get the result that user 1 is available in md1,md2,md3,md4.Is this possible?

Comment: of course it is,specify that in the table array.
srry mate i am currently busy on a project of my own otherwise i would have whipped up a code for you.
try using excels built in macro recorder to and do what your are trying to do>
if you still dont get it, ill help you out

Comment: of course mate... can u attach two sample workbooks and an explanation of what you exactly need? i shall have a look and provide you a solution.
i thought u had given up...

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B19_35dV1ylpZG9RT3ZTQzFRYTQ/edit?usp=sharing

This is a sample excel sheet .. There is sheet 3 and sheet 4 which are given to me and i need a result sheet by a macro or v look up. I have tried a lot of things but couldnt get it done . it would be great if you could help me. Please ask me if you dont understand anything on the sheet.

Comment: Basically in one sheet i have risk id which have two transaction codes and a risk assigned to it.
eg: b001 risk has t1,t2 transation codes and risk is high.

then in the second sheet i have which users have which t codes
eg: user 1 may have t1 t2 t3 transaction code.

in the result i need one user has how many risks. In this example which is above i know user 1 has 1 risk b001 because user 1 has t1 t2 which lead to risk b001.

Comment: hello again 
upload a file in excel use this if it is ok with you or put one in your question http://wikisend.com/

Comment: is this excel sheet fine for you?

Comment: yea dude,
its fine, but im struggling with it... hold on ill try something